# what happens to Schweizer T-Norm when p goes to zero?

Tags: math, artificial-intelligence, fuzzy-logic

I am reading Jang's book of `Neuro-Fuzzy and Soft Computing` and in the 2nd chapter the author talks about Schweizer and Sklar T-Norm which is presented by this equation:
[image: The Schweizer and Sklar T-Norm]

it's a handy T-norm. in the exercises (#20 page 45) it asks what would happen to the `Tss(a,b,p)` if `p->0`
In fact it asks to show that the whole equation is going to be just `ab` in the end.
I tried different things and at last, I used `Ln` but I got this: `-1/p Ln(a^-p + b^-p)` and I have no idea where to go from here!

can anybody suggest anything? thanks for your help.

p.s: is there any simple way of expanding `Ln(x+y)` generally?

Comment: Look what happens to the exponent as `p->0`. What happens to an expression that has such an exponent?

Comment: You may want to try one of the [math stack exchanges](http://stackexchange.com/sites#science), this doesn't have a whole lot to do with programming per se.

Comment: @deceze sorry I though maybe cause it's in an artificial intelligence textbook, this might be a good place for asking.

Comment: @CoconutBandit maybe i left something behind! it asks to show that the whole thing is going to be the product of `a` and `b`. `ab`

Comment: Call us when you're about to *implement* an artificial intelligence in a concrete programming language… :)

Comment: @deceze thank you and thanks for your advice. I will ask it on math stack if i can't find the answer.

Comment: Sorry, I actually misread your question. You need to use the fact that `x = e^{Ln(x)}`. Dont look at the limit of the log-space. Also, wolframalpha would probably help here